# Why Typescript complains that I cannot compare two boolean variables when they are of different value (true,false)?

Tags: angular, typescript

As you can see in the example in the following image, we get this strange error when trying to compare a variable of type boolean against true.

*`this condition will always return 'false' since the types 'false' and 'true' have no overlap`*

Does anyone knows why do we get this error, or what do we miss?
Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Your forEach isn't considered, you should use the stream correctly with a find instead of a variable then a loop.

Comment: Ordinarily you could just say if (limitsReached)  since it's a boolean too. Do you not need a semi-colon after the }) too?

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem with code, people who are volunteering to help need the text of the code. Images of the code are not an acceptable substitute.](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: `true` will **never** equal `false`. The compiler is just telling you this if statement is non-sensical. There is absolutely no time that the contents of the if block will ever get entered. It's dead code and should be removed.

Comment: You are referring to "samlpe" section of my screenshot, and that's true, but this is only a sample.... the same happens a few lines below where the value of limitsReached may changed to true

Answer (score -1):

You can do explicit cast back to `boolean` to fix the issue `limitReached as boolean`:

```js
let items = [1, 2, 3];
let limitReached: boolean = false;

items.forEach(v => {
    if (v == 2) {
        limitReached = true;
    }
});

if ((limitReached as boolean) == true) {
    console.log("true")
}
```